# Put File in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel-5

this is my Class :

```
   <?php


namespace App\Functions;
use http\Env\Response;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class UploadFile
{
    public  function UploadFile($root,Request $request)
  {
      if($request->file('file')!=null){
          if(Storage::put($root.'/'.$request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName(), $request->file('file'))) return response()->json('true');
          return response()->json('false');
      }

  }


}
```

My code uploads the file but puts the file name on a folder name
How to fix this problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8JaO.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify with what you mean with `but puts the file name on a folder name`

Comment: updated please check image

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that "puts the file name on a folder name" means the file is saving as if it were a folder. This would be because you are missing the file extension. You can use `$request->file('file')->getClientOriginalOriginalExtension()` to get this.

Your updated code would be:

```
 <?php

namespace App\Functions;

use http\Env\Response;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class UploadFile
{
    public function UploadFile($root,Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->file('file') != null) {
            if (Storage::put($root . '/' . $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName() . '.' . $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension(), $request->file('file'))) return response()->json('true');
            return response()->json('false');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work But this time it named the folder as follows. 127_0_0_1 (2).sql.sql

Comment: 127_0_0_1 (2) .sql is my file